# Erroneous result using inverse Vincenty's formula in C

Tags: c

I have written a C script to implement the inverse Vincenty's formula to calculate the distance between two sets of GPS coordinates based on the equations shown at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae

However, my results are different to the results given by this online calculator https://www.cqsrg.org/tools/GCDistance/ and Google maps. My results are consistently around 1.18 times the result of the online calculator.

My function is below, any tips on where I could be going wrong would be very much appreciated!

```
double get_distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2)
{
  double rad_eq = 6378137.0;             //Radius at equator
  double flattening = 1 / 298.257223563; //flattenig of earth
  double rad_pol = (1 - flattening) * rad_eq;     //Radius at poles
  
  double U1,U2,L,lambda,old_lambda,sigma,sin_sig,cos_sig,alpha,cos2sigmam,A,B,C,u_sq,delta_s,dis;

  //Convert to radians
  lat1=M_PI*lat1/180.0;
  lat2=M_PI*lat2/180.0;
  lon1=M_PI*lon1/180.0;
  lon2=M_PI*lon2/180.0;

  //Calculate U1 and U2
  U1=atan((1-flattening)*tan(lat1));
  U2=atan((1-flattening)*tan(lat2));
  
  L=lon2-lon1;
  
  lambda=L;
  
  double tolerance=pow(10.,-12.);//iteration tollerance should give 0.6mm
  double diff=1.;
  
  while (abs(diff)>tolerance)
    {
    
    sin_sig=sqrt(pow(cos(U2)*sin(lambda),2.)+pow(cos(U1)*sin(U2)-(sin(U1)*cos(U2)*cos(lambda)),2.));
    
    
    cos_sig=sin(U1)*cos(U2)+cos(U1)*cos(U2)*cos(lambda);
    
    sigma=atan(sin_sig/cos_sig);
    alpha=asin((cos(U1)*cos(U2)*sin(lambda))/(sin_sig));
    cos2sigmam=cos(sigma)-(2*sin(U1)*sin(U2))/((pow(cos(alpha),2.)));
    C=(flattening/16)*pow(cos(alpha),2.)*(4+(flattening*(4-(3*pow(cos(alpha),2.)))));
    old_lambda=lambda;
    lambda=L+(1-C)*flattening*sin(alpha)*(sigma+C*sin_sig*(cos2sigmam+C*cos_sig*(-1+2*pow(cos2sigmam,2.))));
    diff=abs(old_lambda-lambda);
    }
  
  u_sq=pow(cos(alpha),2.)*((pow(rad_eq,2.)-pow(rad_pol,2.))/(pow(rad_pol,2.)));
  A=1+(u_sq/16384)*(4096+(u_sq*(-768+(u_sq*(320-(175*u_sq))))));
  B=(u_sq/1024)*(256+(u_sq*(-128+(u_sq*(74-(47*u_sq))))));
  delta_s=B*sin_sig*(cos2sigmam+(B/4)*(cos_sig*(-1+(2*pow(cos2sigmam,2.)))-(B/6)*cos2sigmam*(-3+(4*pow(sin_sig,2.)))*(-3+(4*pow(cos2sigmam,2.)))));
  dis=rad_pol*A*(sigma-delta_s);
  
  //Returns distance in metres
  return dis;
}
```

Comment: Please use `fabs()` not `abs()` or you'll lose the fractional parts.

Comment: CRalli, Tip: enable all warnings to find issues like `abs(some_double)` quickly.

Comment: Aside: `pow(some_double, 2.)` is an inefficient way to square a number.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is not symmetric:

```
cos_sig = sin(U1)*cos(U2)
        + cos(U1)*cos(U2) * cos(lambda);
```

And turns out to be wrong, a `sin` is missing.

Another style of formatting (one including some whitespace) could also help.

---

Besides the `fabs` for `abs` and one `sin` for that `cos` I also changed the loop; there were two `abs()`-calls and `diff` had to be preset with the while-loop.

I inserted a `printf` to see how the value progresses.

Some parentheses can be left out. These formulas are really difficult to realize. Some more helper variables could be useful in this jungle of nested math operations.

```
do {

    sin_sig = sqrt(pow(        cos(U2) * sin(lambda), 2)
                 + pow(cos(U1)*sin(U2)
                 -    (sin(U1)*cos(U2) * cos(lambda))
                   , 2)
                );

    cos_sig = sin(U1) * sin(U2)
            + cos(U1) * cos(U2) * cos(lambda);

    sigma = atan2(sin_sig, cos_sig);

    alpha = asin(cos(U1) * cos(U2) * sin(lambda)
                / sin_sig
            );

    double cos2alpha = cos(alpha)*cos(alpha);      // helper var.

    cos2sigmam = cos(sigma) - 2*sin(U1)*sin(U2) / cos2alpha;

    C = (flat/16) * cos2alpha * (4 + flat * (4 - 3*cos2alpha));

    old_lambda = lambda;

    lambda = L + (1-C) * flat * sin(alpha)
                *(sigma + C*sin_sig
                    *(cos2sigmam + C*cos_sig
                    *(2 * pow(cos2sigmam, 2) - 1)
                    )
                );

    diff = fabs(old_lambda - lambda);
    printf("%.12f\n", diff);

} while (diff > tolerance);
```

For 80,80, 0,0 the output is (in km):

```
0.000885870048
0.000000221352
0.000000000055
0.000000000000
9809.479224
```

which corresponds to the millimeter with WGS-84.